# What is the replacement for scene.update()?

Tags: scene

It seems the following is no longer available in blender 2.8 api

```py
bpy.context.scene.update()
```

How do we update objects in the scene that have been changed by the script now?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Many instructions point to:

```
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

That's also what's mentioned in [API documentation](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Scene_and_Object_API)

Comment: Including https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140789/what-is-the-replacement-for-scene-update#comment240850_140802

Comment: doesn't always work like in this scenario https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/315160/gn-setting-modifier-property-via-python-does-not-update-the-3d-view

Answer (score 7):

> **[Dependency graph API changes](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/commitdiff/e693918d40741b0839cea84d2e0c386cc262e0c3)**
>
> Main goal here is to make it obvious and predictable about what is
>   going on.
>
> Summary of changes.
>
> - Access to dependency graph is now only possible to a fully evaluated   graph. This is now done via context.evaluated_depsgraph_get().
>
>   The call will ensure both relations and datablocks are updated.
>
>   This way we don't allow access to some known bad state of the graph,
>     and also making explicit that getting update dependency graph is not
>     cheap.
> - Access to evaluated ID is now possible via id.evaluated_get().
>
>   It was already possible to get evaluated ID via dependency graph,
>     but that was a bit confusing why access to original is done via ID
>     and to evaluated via depsgraph.
>
>   If datablock is not covered by dependency graph it will be returned 
>     as-is.
> - Similarly, request for original from an ID which is not evaluated   will return ID as-is.
> - Removed scene.update().
>
>   This is very expensive to update all the view layers.
> - Added depsgraph.update().
>
>   Now when temporary changes to objects are to be done, this is to
>     happen on original object and then dependency graph is to be
>     updated.

Some fiddling in python console.

```
>>> dg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get(
evaluated_depsgraph_get()
Context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
Get the dependency graph for the current scene and view layer,
 to access to data-blocks with animation and modifiers applied. 
 If any data-blocks have been edited, the dependency graph will be updated. 
 This invalidates all references to evaluated data-blocks from the dependency graph.
>>> dg = C.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
>>> ob = C.object
>>> ob.evaluated_get(
evaluated_get()
Object.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
Get corresponding evaluated ID from the given dependency graph
>>> ob.evaluated_get(dg)
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> dg.update(
update()
Depsgraph.update()
Re-evaluate any modified data-blocks, for example for animation or modifiers. 
 This invalidates all references to evaluated data-blocks from this dependency graph.
>>> dg.update()
```

This is all pretty new and TBH haven't tested it against how the old scene update was used. Speculating, it appears can evaluate changes to a single object based on the depsgraph, without the need to expensively update scene and all objects in it.

Comment: Replaced bpy.context.scene.update() with
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
dg.update()
works for me, incidently bpy.context.view_layer.update() also gets the job done but I will accept this as the correct answer.

Comment: I can't make much sense out of the python console part in grey. What is the difference between the >>> segments versus those that are not indented?

Comment: `>>>` is the console prompt, anything after I've typed in. If ends with say `(` I've hit autocomplete and pasted that.  Go to the console and have a fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

```
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

works but as mentioned here : [corner cases in blender](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#unfortunate-corner-cases)

This method can also help in removing these corner cases but use every time you toggle the property.

I experimented with it, it remove the bug of rendering the object while I set the `obj.hide_render = True.`

Answer (score 2):

wrestled with this till I was ready to tear out my hair.  here's a hacky catchall to force an update when all the other solutions fail.

```
for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    obj.hide_render = obj.hide_render
```

Comment: That was useful, thank you (I used something similar to update some changes in grease pencil layers)