# Blender 2.8, Getting Script to Update a Driver

Tags: python, drivers

I have a for loop (A) that is updating a Custom Property (B) that is a driver for a Cube's X-location (C) which is supposed to update the Cube's location (D) and Export each incremental change to a .obj file, HOWEVER... The changes are not updating before the .obj is exported and the Cube in each of the seven exported .obj files is staying in the starting position.

I have tried *bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()* but it doesn't seem to be doing [what people say it's supposed to do](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/140789/what-is-the-replacement-for-scene-update), which is work as a replacement for *scene.update()*, which doesn't work in Blender 2.8 anymore?

What am I missing?[image: Cube Is not updating it's position]