# how to update the dependency graph after switching a scene

Tags: python

how to update the dpendency graph after switching a scene?
after i`m open the file I see the switching was successful
but during the code it does not change.

I think to change frame number as a hack,but.
there is any official non hackish way to do it ?

```
scene = bpy.data.scenes.get(self.data.scene_name)
```

result : <bpy_struct, Scene("Scene") at 0x0000023020016048>

```
dgutils.switch_to_scene(scene)
print(bpy.context.scene)
```

result: <bpy_struct, Scene("Night") at 0x000002302003C088>

```
depsgraph = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

bpy.context.view_layer.update()
depsgraph.update()
print(bpy.context.scene)
```

result: <bpy_struct, Scene("Night") at 0x000002302003C088>

Update:
Code works fine when using -background from cmd
otherwise the dependency graph not update.

Comment: I think you want `bpy.context.view_layer.update()` but see [this answer and comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140802/42221) for an alternative that suggests your approach should work.  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Thanks Marty but I already mentioned bpy.context.view_layer.update()
I also mentioned when it does work. 
Generally things are not consistent and its frustrating.
tried also all the other mambo jambo hacks.

Comment: In that case I suspect that you have hit a bug and might consider filing a bug report.