# GN: Setting modifier property via python does not update the 3D view

Tags: python, scripting, modifiers, geometry-nodes

I copied full datapath for my property Vertices X as shown below and set it via python using `bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 5`. The value will update when you hover over it but it does not update the 3D View evidenced in the GN tree socket value it's still 2 instead of 5. Why? I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76693717/blender-viewport-not-updating-via-python-script-even-if-geometry-node-parameter) but no answer. Is this a bug?

I also tried `context.view_layer.update()` but that didn't help...

[image]

I noticed that when I manually toggle back and forth it works but if I do it with script it doesn't:

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 5
bpy.ops.object.mode_set_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.mode_set_toggle()
```

I also found [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/140802/184387) and tried this:

```
dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
dg.update()
```

But that also doesn't work. Is this maybe a bug I should log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
import bpy

cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

cube.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Socket_2"] = 2

cube.modifiers.update()

cube.update_tag()
```

About `cube.modifiers.update()` the Python console says

> update() .. method:: update() Execute the properties update callback.
> .. note::    This is called when assigning a property,    however in
> rare cases it's useful to call explicitly.